# Unable to install required package (rabbitmq-server) before Travis CI build

Tags: rabbitmq, continuous-integration, travis-ci, sha

Since today I experience the following issue with Travis CI: the required package specified in `before_install` section of `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq rabbitmq-server
```

cannot be installed, breaking the build.

> Response as shown Travis console log:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get update -qq
> W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg: Signature by key 15866BAFD9BCC4F3C1E0DFC7D69548E1C17EAB57 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
> $ sudo apt-get install -qq rabbitmq-server
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> The command "sudo apt-get install -qq rabbitmq-server" failed and exited with 100 during .
> Your build has been stopped.
> ```

How would I overcome this problem? I have tried to replicate the issue locally, but it seems to be not reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

I searched Google with this search string - `"failed and exited with 100" apt install` - this is the first hit:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7998

Comment: Do you think I am unable to Google? Also, please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your question gave no information about what you had tried to resolve this, so yes, my first thought is that you had not searched for the error message. I could just as easily link to this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. That issue in the travis-ci repo links to several others, one of which may be what you are running into.